# This operation has been disabled in the commmand-map cannot be used =: SET - Redis sentinel connection error but redis works

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

This operation has been disabled in the commmand-map cannot be used =: SET, error while connecting redis sentinel. Here is the code sample..

```
`var options = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints = { "host1:26379", "host2:26379", "host3:26379" },
    ServiceName = "mymaster",
    CommandMap = CommandMap.Sentinel,
    Password = ********
};

var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.SentinelConnect(options);

var db = connection.GetDatabase();

db.StringSet("mykey", "myvalue");`
```

trying to update redis sentinel

Answer (score 0):

Redis Sentinel offers a very limited set of commands, which includes `PING`, support for pub/sub and the `SENTINEL` subcommands, as explained in the [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/sentinel/#sentinel-commands). Not sure what you are trying to do here as there is often no need to connect directly to these nodes, however the `SET` command is simply not supported in Redis Sentinel.